# 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN

Tags: html, iframe

Im trying to embeded some site like this

```
<iframe src="http://somesite.com"></iframe>
```

But im getting this error.

```
Refused to display in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'
```

Is there a way how to fix this error?
Site that I need to embeded isnt mine

Comment: Googling the error message or `X-Frame-Options` will answer the question

Comment: Site that I need to embeded isnt mine.

Comment: Then there’s likely nothing you can do - if it were possible to work around it, it would have no purpose. You would have to scrape the site’s contents on server side and display them in an `iframe` from your own server, but that’s very complex

Comment: If the site to be embedded is also mine then how can I handle this error. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask site owner to change access for your domain
or
you can try to do it from php side using curl or file_get_contents.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick, it gets the contents of remote site and pastes it.

```
    <?php
        $url = "https://google.com";
        echo '<base href="'.$url.'" />' . file_get_contents($url);
    ?>
```

Comment: Hello Edward! Please assist. How can we implement this solution in a modal window?